# Lua/Corona Attempt to Index a Boolean Value

Tags: lua, osx-mountain-lion, coronasdk

It looks like I am having problems with transitioning from my level select page to my first level. I think it might be that I am missing something in my level 1, but I don't know exactly.

### levelSelect.lua

```
module(..., package.seeall)

local director = require ("director")

local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

local widget = require( "widget" )

-- Function to handle button events
local function handleButtonEventLevel1( event )
local phase = event.phase
if "ended" == phase then
    director:changeScene("lvl1")
    end
end

--local function goLevel1()
    --director:changeScene("lvl1")
    --return true
--end
--widget.newButton:addEventListener("tap", goLevel1)

local function handleButtonEventToPage( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    if "ended" == phase then
        director:changeScene("page")
    end
end

-- Main function - MUST return a display.newGroup()
function new()
    local localGroup = display.newGroup()

    local background = display.newImage("bigtestsky.png")
    background.x=150
    background.y=250

    local myButton = widget.newButton
    {
        left = 25,
        top = 25,
        width = 100,
        height = 50,
        defaultFile = "default.png",
        overFile = "over.png",
        label = "1",
        font = "LS",
        fontSize = 20,
        labelColor = { default = {0,0,50}, over = {0,0,255} },
        onEvent = handleButtonEventLevel1,
    }

    local myButton = widget.newButton
    {
        left = 25,
        top = 415,
        width = 100,
        height = 50,
        defaultFile = "default.png",
        overFile = "over.png",
        label = "BACK",
        font = "LS",
        fontSize = 20,
        labelColor = { default = {0,0,50}, over = {0,0,255} },
        onEvent = handleButtonEventToPage,
    }

    return localGroup
end
```

### lvl1.lua

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
local widget = require( "widget" )
```

(This is what I mean about missing something in the first level. Could someone please help?)

---

```
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        .../myName/Desktop/Bubbles! App/director.lua:116: in function 'loadScene'
        .../myName/Desktop/Bubbles! App/director.lua:394: in function 'changeScene'
        ...myName/Desktop/Bubbles! App/levelSelect.lua:14: in function '_onEvent'
        ?: in function '?'
        ?: in function <?:405>
        ?: in function <?:218>
```

Comment: So... Where did this attempt to index a boolean value error come from? This is really important information. If you got that error, then it should've pointed to a file name and line number, such as: `stdin:1: attempt to index a boolean value`.

Comment: File: .../myName/Desktop/Bubbles! App/director.lua
Line: 116

Attempt to index a boolean value

Comment: stack traceback:
 [C]: ?
 .../myName/Desktop/Bubbles! App/director.lua:116: in function 'loadScene'
 .../myName/Desktop/Bubbles! App/director.lua:394: in function 'changeScene'
 ...myName/Desktop/Bubbles! App/levelSelect.lua:14: in function '_onEvent'
 ?: in function '?'
 ?: in function <?:405>
 ?: in function <?:218>

Answer (score 0):

These are due to some issues with your class: `lvl1.lua`.

If such error occurs, open director.lua analyse the error return line. This will help you to find what the real problem is.

Here, you must write more lines in your `lvl1.lua` as below:

```
module(...,package.seeall) -- If this line is not written, then the package will not be loaded.

function new()   -- Module 'lvl1' must have a new() function
local localGroup = display.newGroup() -- The scene should create a display group
    local physics = require("physics")
    physics.start()
    local widget = require( "widget" )
    print("Inside lvl1...")

return localGroup; -- And the scene should return the previously created display group.
end
```

Keep Coding.............. :)

Comment: The button does nothing now, it doesn't even go to a new scene. There are no errors, though :)

Comment: Oh, never mind, I get it, I have to change the print statement. Sorry :D